# Node js performance when loading modules

Tags: performance, node.js

I have several custom modules that I call hundreds of times per second and I want to make sure there isn't a performance impact due to calling these modules.

EXAMPLE MODULE - random-string.js

```
module.exports = function() {

    // Required modules
    var logs = require(__dirname + '/logs.js'); // Custom logger
    var uuid = require('node-uuid'); // Simple, fast generation of RFC4122 UUIDS

    var randomString = uuid.v1() + uuid.v4();
    logs.dev(randomString);

    return randomString;
};
```

If I am  calling this module from another (ie. require(__dirname + '/random-string.js')) and it's being called hundreds of times per second, is this doing a read to disk EACH time to load logs.js or node-uuid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, modules loaded by `require` are cached by node (so it's not going to disk every time), but there's still no good reason to load the module on every function call: there is still *some* overhead associated with the call to `require` and looking up the cached module object.

Why not just load dependencies at the top of your module?

```
var logs = require(__dirname + '/logs.js'); // Custom logger
var uuid = require('node-uuid'); // Simple, fast generation of RFC4122 UUIDS

module.exports = function() {

    var randomString = uuid.v1() + uuid.v4();
    logs.dev(randomString);

    return randomString;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

No. Module return values are cached and reused.

Though a better way to structure your code would be:

```
var logs = require(__dirname + '/logs.js'); // Custom logger
var uuid = require('node-uuid'); // Simple, fast generation of RFC4122 UUIDS

module.exports = function() {
  var randomString = uuid.v1() + uuid.v4();
  logs.dev(randomString);
  return randomString;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Node.js caches the modules so they are loaded only first time they are requested. See http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching for the details.